# Single word meaning choose an option of delivery or pick up

Tags: single-word-requests

Naming a step in a process is difficult when two options with very different meanings exist -

1. Delivery
2. Pick-up

If you are choosing delivery obviously you could use 'Delivery Address' or something.

If you are choosing pick-up you could use simply 'Pick-up confirmation' or something.

But if you wanted a one or two word way to describe the step of choosing one of the options and then entering an address or something what would it be?

Comment: How is this being used? If this is an online form, you would just use a menu or radio buttons to choose between them, you don't need a common term.

Comment: Imagine a 'wizard' where the steps are defined and the name of the step would describe the action you will take.  When that step is chosen you would then pick your option in a form like you mentioned.

Comment: See http://mypizza.com/restaurants/ma/arlington/02474/sabatino-s-italian-kitchen-arlington/menu There's no label for the pickup and delivery buttons.

Comment: Use Delivery Method  which could then have choices of "Delivery" and "Pick-up"

Comment: @Jim That does sounds feasible, I wonder if there is any other word beside 'Delivery' that would be synonymous, just curious.

Comment: I think "Delivery Options" is pretty standard: http://www.ticketmaster.com/h/delivery.html

Comment: Perhaps *procurement*, but it seems a little business formal, and not consumer friendly.

Comment: Perhaps a generic like "Order Options" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Note that whatever you choose must be understood by your audience. They'd probably understand, "I want delivery/Pickup". But look at the biggest brand websites that have physical presence. See what terminology they use and realize why they are, somehow, still able to effectively communicate in a succinct manner and sell product without a single word for x.

Answer (score 3):

"delivery option" or "delivery method".  These would parallel "shipping option" or "shipping method", respectively, if you are collecting that information as well.  (Likewise with "payment option" or "payment method", where they specify which kind of credit card.)

Be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

What we're trying to describe is how the customer will `receive` their goods.
For example,

> would you like to receive your groceries through pickup or delivery?

Similar in pattern to other verbs, we would expect a `-ment` / `-tion` word for this:

- procure => procurement
- achieve => achievement
- fulfill => fulfillment
- disburse => disbursement
- distribute => distribution

For example, we would expect to have something like

- receive => recievement

However, `receivement` is not a real word. Instead, the correct word for this seems to be `receipt`. Definition being

> the action of receiving something or the fact of its being received

Unfortunately, `receipt` is more commonly associated with the piece of paper that confirms `reciept` rather than the event itself, so `receipt method` is likely not going to cut it.

In reality, the best option is probably one of the following, depending on your usecase:

- fulfillment method
- distribution method

Those are not very user friendly words, which is probably why most companies avoid labeling this in user interfaces.